# Unknown Language Random Code Generator

Tags: c#, java, c++

I am trying to understand this code and I am not sure what language it is.  It seems to be Java but I am not sure.  I apologize if I am posting this incorrectly.  I am volunteering and helping with a calendar and trying to find a random generator to work with basic.  I am immediately trying to understand what this is doing.

```
private static uint GetUint()
  {
   m_z = 36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16);
   m_w = 18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16);
   return (m_z << 16) + m_w;
  }


public static double GetUniform()
 {
  // 0 <= u < 2^32
  uint u = GetUint();
  // The magic number below is 1/(2^32 + 2).
  // The result is strictly between 0 and 1.
  return (u + 1.0) * 2.328306435454494e-10;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a double LCG implemented in C# (I say C# instead of Java because IIRC Java doesn't have `uint`). You can find more about LCGs [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Still, most dialects of BASIC have some random number generator built in, typically using the instructions `RANDOMIZE` for initializing it and `RAND` or `RANDOM` to get a random number.

Answer (score 8):

It is C#, and the code is from here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/SimpleRNG.aspx?display=Print

It is used to generate random numbers. There's quite a bit more info on it at that link above. To find it I Googled the 2.38... number, because it looked familiar.

Comment: Thanks! I think I saw this once about ten years ago in a class I was taking :)

Answer (score 7):

It's should be C#.

- C++'s `public` and `private` must be followed by a `:`.
- Java doesn't have `uint`.
- The naming convention (CamelCase) looks like a .NET language, and the syntax is C-like.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the naming conventions (methods starting in uppercase), the data types (uint, double), the keywords (private, public, static), the programming conventions (braces in a separate line) and the operators (>>, +, *, &) I'm pretty sure the programming language used in the above snippet it's C# .